# moving a repo to a new branch/repo

Tags: git, command-line

I just pushed a php project I'm building to my remote repo called php then I realized I need to put it in a sub dir of that repo.  I'm a little new to git and I don't know how to take the local repo and poush it to the sub dir in the remote repo.  Can anyone tell me what I need to do?  Do I merge it, move it or what?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add an existing git project to another existing git repo would be to via adding it as a submodule.

```
git submodule add [URL to Git repo] 
git submodule init
```

Initialize the repository’s submodules by running `git submodule init` followed by `git submodule update`.

Change into the submodule’s directory and checkout your desired branch of the project you added, for example, `git checkout master`

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the history of your repo, using `git filter-branch`, [like so](https://gist.github.com/fabiomaggio/ce7ecd7dffd27b32a45325204288efce) :

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mkdir -p /path/to/tmp; mv * /path/to/tmp; mkdir subdir; mv /path/to/tmp/* subdir/' --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty -- --all
```

or [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) :

```
git filter-repo --path-rename /:subdir/
```

Then `push -f` your rewritten `master` branch.